# Multi-threading locks test

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, locking

I have a class which uses a read-write lock.

I want to see if I've locked and protected all the methods correctly.
Is there a design pattern for a test to check if the locks are set correctly ?

**Edit:**
Some clarifications:

It's a C# code derived from a C++/CLI Code which has locks in the C++ level... Not that simple. That's why I'm looking for a design for a test, not for a design for how to lock it.

There are a few things that need to be checks while multithreading:

No Deadlocks (Most obvious)
Correctness (If I update it in 1 thread it will be seen in the other)
Atomic write (If I write in one thread, I will able to read only when the full value is written)
Fairness (Might be more theoretical to prove, should be true if i use Mutex anyway)

Comment: Does "carefully" count as a design pattern?

Comment: I'm afraid that "carefully" won't cover all the bad situations

Comment: -1 for worst use of 'Design Pattern' of the week.

Comment: (given that the post is +2 and -0, I think we can assume that either that is a metaphysical -1, or the downvote hit a race condition and didn't save)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to read up on SyncLock and SyncRoot which are used to create a common pattern on how to lock your objects. Since you do not want to lock an enitre object you often have a SyncRoot that you lock on.

An example for this is ArrayList or ICollection which both have a SyncRoot that you should use to lock the collection. You can read more about [Thread Synchronization on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx).

But generally it's just like Marc pointed out, be carefull, test, test, test and do some more test!

**Example of SyncLock**

```
public class Person
{
    public decimal Salary { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public readonly object SyncRoot = new object();
}
```

You can then approach a locking like this:

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Bill", Salary = 1000000 };

lock(person.SyncRoot)
{
    IncreasSalary();
}
```

A [bad pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/springboard/archive/2008/07/30/lock-this-bad-locking-patterns.aspx) is to do `lock(this)` **NEVER** do that!

There is also somthing called [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) which is not specific to .NET you might also want to read this paper on ["Strategized Locking, Thread-safe Interface, and Scoped Locking"](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/locking-patterns.pdf).

**Testing for thread safety**

If you want to test for thread safety I recommend you check out ["Unit test for thread safety"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715822/unit-test-for-thread-safe-ness), the accepted answer points to [Microsoft Chess](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/) which can help you identify deadlocks in your application.

Comment: It's a C# code derived from a C++/CLI Code which has locks in the C++ level... Not that simple. That's why I'm looking for a design for a test, not for a design for how to lock it.

Comment: @Yochai, so you want to stress your application into deadlock? So what you are looking for is a test-strategy on how to verify that your application do not go into deadlock? Is that correct?

Comment: Multithreading tests... Thread doesn't deadlock. Fairness. Values get read correctly, not in middle of write. There's more to multithreading than deadlocks

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your question a bit so there is no further missunderstanding.

Comment: You should explain why you think that `lock (this)` is never OK.

Comment: @jfauffin, I linked to a block post on MSDN that explained why you should never do that. In short, it violates the guidelines and can cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

You know the problem, that's step one. It is (usually) NP-complete... however there are tools:

- helgrind

> part of the valgrind toolkit; this will be able to verify the use of the most common synchronisation primitives; you might be able to tell it about your own primitives.

- Intel Parallel Inspector

Similarly let's you describe your own primitives for validation during use. See [Intel Inspector reports a data race in my spinlock implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470741/problem-with-own-spinlock-implementation)

**Update** I just found that GNU libstdc(++) and GNU gcc have improved their support of Helgrind substantially, refer to the 4.6.x release notes and [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html#debug.races)

It also links the following additional tools

- [Data Race Detection](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html)
- [ThreadSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/)

Comment: Sry kind of missed the C# tag. There should be no real difference there, but it will make it harder to apply these tools